# Angular 2 E2E Test cases runs on local system but not on server?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I have deployed my angular2 app using ng build --prod.

Now When I Test My app using protractor in local system, all my test cases run successfully i.e. links are being clicked, users are getting created & deleted.

But When I deployed the code on server , few testcases run successfully like creating & deleting users but few test cases like drag & drop, opening modal always give time out.

> asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 60 seconds

After building angular2 app , I am using express to host the app.

Configurations:

Local: Windows 7 
Server : Windows server 2012 R2 Standard Build

Are there any extra configurations required?

Thanks